# How do I find the source of an error?

Tags: cron, log-messages

I'm seeing the following error when running cron (in terminal via drush and on screen via the status report page.

> Error: Call to a member function getScriptTag() on a non-object in /home/loktah/public_html/includes/common.inc(1762) : eval()'d code, line 2

I'm not sure where to even start looking for the source. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line 1762 is inside [`drupal_eval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_eval/6), in Drupal 6. You need to check  those nodes that use the PHP filter and call `getScriptTag()` on a variable that doesn't contain a PHP object.

It happens during cron tasks because one of the implementations of `hook_cron()` indirectly calls `node_view()` on some nodes.

Comment: Thank you. After some searching I discovered that my client pasted javascript into text fields on nodes.